# Error: "Invalid JSON response" when I try to update data with DT::replaceData() [shiny]

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt, reactive

I'm trying to update a table by changing the class of each variable (string or character). 
I have tried several methods but most of them just don't render something. With the method used in the code bellow, I can just change one time the type of the variable and then, the table is not reactive anymore.

Do you have an idea of what should I do?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

current_stage <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

mydata <- reactive({
  df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
  current_stage$data <- df
  df 
})


updateData = reactive({

df = mydata()
map(1:ncol(df), function(i){
  if(length(input[[paste0("col", i)]])>0){
    if (input[[paste0("col", i)]]=="num"){
      df[,i] <<- unlist(df[,i]) %>% as.numeric
    } else if (input[[paste0("col", i)]]=="cat"){
      df[,i] <<- unlist(df[,i]) %>% as.character
    }
  }
})
#current_stage$data <- df
df
})

output$tableau <- DT::renderDataTable({
  df <-  current_stage$data

  class <- map_df(df, typeof)

  class <- gsub("double", "numeric", class)

  class <- gsub("integer", "numeric", class)

  tableSelectInput <- map(1:ncol(df),
                        function(i) {
                          if (class[i] =="numeric"){
                            opt1 <- "num"
                            opt2 <- "cat"
                          }else{ 
                            opt1 <- "cat"
                            opt2 <- "num"
                          }
                          selectInput(
                            inputId = paste0("col", i),
                            label = NULL, selected = opt1,
                            choices = c(opt1, opt2))
                        }
   ) 

# I didn't find a more elegant way to turn '[[ ]]' in '[ ]'
l <-  length(tableSelectInput)
selectin  <-  1:l
type_cat <-  1:l
for (i in 1:l) {
  selectin[i] = as.character(tableSelectInput[[i]])
  pos=gregexpr("selected>",selectin[i])[[1]][1]
  type_cat[i] = substr(selectin[i],(pos+9),(pos+11))
}


col_names = paste0(colnames(df), " <br/><em>(",type_cat,")</em><br/>", selectin)
isolate(DT::datatable(
  current_stage$data,
  options = list(
    preDrawCallback = JS("function() { 
                         Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
    drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());

}")
  ),
  colnames =col_names, 
  editable = TRUE,
  escape=FALSE,
  selection = list(target = 'column')))
 }, server=FALSE)




  output$log <- renderPrint({

  updateData()
 })
 output$log2 <- renderPrint({
  map_df(updateData(),class)
 })
})


ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("My Awesome Shiny App"),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
     DT::DTOutput("tableau"),
     # Show log
     verbatimTextOutput("log"),
     verbatimTextOutput("log2")
    )
  )
) 
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I think there is something wrong with the input button call "col1", "col2", etc..
I should maybe create them in a different way but I don't I am just stuck for the moment. Someone could give me an advice?

Kevin

**Update:**
I have tried this code but it looks to have some trouble with Ajax:
*DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"*

```
        library(DT)
        library(shiny)
        library(tidyverse)


        server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

          current_stage <- reactiveValues(data=NULL, init=NULL,n=0)

          mydata <- reactive({
            df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
            current_stage$data <- df
            current_stage$init <- df
            df 
          })


          updateData = reactive({
            # input$refresh
            # df$ID <<- c(df$ID[n], df$ID[-n])
            df = mydata()
            if( !is.null(current_stage$data)){
              df <-  current_stage$data
              map(1:ncol(df), function(i){
                if(length(input[[paste0("col", i)]])>0){
                  if (input[[paste0("col", i)]]=="num"){
                    df[,i] <<- unlist(current_stage$init [,i]) %>% as.numeric
                  } else if (input[[paste0("col", i)]]=="cat"){
                    df[,i] <<- unlist(current_stage$init [,i]) %>% as.character
                  }
                }
              })}


            # if(length(input[[paste0("col", 1)]])>0){
            #   if (input[[paste0("col", 1)]]=="num"){
            #     # message(proxy)
            #     df[,1] <- unlist(df[,1]) %>% as.numeric
            #     #       # mydata()[,1] <- paste(proxy[,1],"ok")
            #   } else if (input[[paste0("col", 1)]]=="cat"){
            #     #       # message(proxy)
            #     df[,1] <- unlist(df[,1]) %>% as.character
            #   }}
            current_stage$data <- df
            df
          })

          output$tableau <- DT::renderDataTable({
            #df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("model")
            df <-  mydata()
            class <- map_df(df, typeof)
            class <- gsub("double", "numeric", class)
            class <- gsub("integer", "numeric", class)
            tableSelectInput <- map(1:ncol(df),
                                    function(i) {
                                      if (class[i] =="numeric"){
                                        opt1 <- "num"
                                        opt2 <- "cat"
                                      }else{ 
                                        opt1 <- "cat"
                                        opt2 <- "num"
                                      }
                                      selectInput(
                                        inputId = paste0("col", i),
                                        label = NULL, selected = opt1,
                                        choices = c(opt1, opt2))
                                    }
            ) 

            # I didn't find a more elegant way to turn '[[ ]]' in '[ ]'
            l <-  length(tableSelectInput)
            selectin  <-  1:l
            type_cat <-  1:l
            for (i in 1:l) {
              selectin[i] = as.character(tableSelectInput[[i]])
              pos=gregexpr("selected>",selectin[i])[[1]][1]
              type_cat[i] = substr(selectin[i],(pos+9),(pos+11))
            }

            col_names = paste0( colnames(df), " <br/><em>(",type_cat,")</em><br/>", selectin)
            DT::datatable(isolate(
              updateData()),
              options = list(
                preDrawCallback = JS("function() { 
                                     Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
                drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
        }")
              ),
              colnames =col_names, 
              editable = TRUE,
              escape=FALSE,
              selection = list(target = 'column'))
          }, server=FALSE)

          proxy <- dataTableProxy('tableau')

          observe({
            replaceData(proxy, updateData(), resetPaging = TRUE )
          })

          output$log <- renderPrint({
            updateData()
          })

        })

        ui = shinyUI(
          fluidPage(
            titlePanel("My Awesome Shiny App"),

            # Show a plot of the generated distribution
            mainPanel(
              DT::DTOutput("tableau"),
              # Show log
              verbatimTextOutput("log")
            )
          )
        ) 
        runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `replaceData` with a reactiveValues object rather than a reactive() object? I have never been able to make a line like `replaceData(proxy, updateData(), resetPaging = TRUE )` work. Have you also tried `observeEvent(input$tableu_cell_edit, ...)` rather than just observe()?

Comment: Hey @RDavey, I think I found a trick but I don't remember well, it was 2 years ago :) Thank for the answer.